# Getting error while running HUGO project - error calling ExecuteAsTemplate: type <nil> not supported in Resource transformations

Tags: hugo

I have developed the website using `Hugo` and checked in to `Git` from Windows 11 machine.
Everything was working fine and now, I have downloaded same working code from `Git` to a different windows machine. But it's throwing the below error

> at <resources.ExecuteAsTemplate>: error calling ExecuteAsTemplate: type  not supported in Resource transformations

I am not able to understand why there is dependency on host machine? I see both my devices have the same HUGO version!

> hugo v0.110.0-e32a493b7826d02763c3b79623952e625402b168+extended windows/amd64 BuildDate=2023-01-17T12:16:09Z VendorInfo=gohugoio

The link below says that "something required by your project’s templates is not there" in new device

https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/error-calling-executeastemplate-type-nil/29272/11

but I am not able to find which is that dependency!